# Chart.js reduce canvas size without changing the size of the chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js, radar-chart

I have a radar chart with the following canvas properties:

```js
ctx.canvas.width = 600;
ctx.canvas.height = 550;
```

The chart displays fine but the canvas seems too large as the chart has a lot of white space around it. I have tried reducing the size of the canvas but this reduces the size of the chart which I do not want.

Any advice?

Regards,

Sarah

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Charts.js graph not scaling to canvas size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512001/charts-js-graph-not-scaling-to-canvas-size)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set responsible to false, per this SO duplicate question / answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281488/3589609

```
 options: {
                responsive: false
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you initialize the canvas with smaller dimensions then?

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```