# Charts.js graph not scaling to canvas size

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to make a graph with Charts.js (current one is just a really simple example I'm trying to get working, somewhat taken from the Chart.js documentation) and the graph isn't scaling to the size of the canvas I'm giving it. Here is all the relevant code.

To import it:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Then, I connect it to a javascript file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stats_tab.js"></script>
```

I have my canvas set up:

```
        <div id="graph_2015" class ="stats_box">
            <h4>Graph 2015</h4>
            Text
            <canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
```

And then finally in stats_tab.js, I have the following code:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    data: [1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,4]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
        }
    });
}
```

The graph displays nicely, but it refuses to scale to the size of the canvas I gave it. There is also no css relevant to any of the divs involved. The inspect feature on chrome lets me know that the final graph is 676 by 676 instead of the 200 by 200 I specified. Not really sure what's going on.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to update the ratio of your chart check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594025/chart-js-aspect-ratio-forced-height/67540672#67540672

Answer (score 103):

The width and height property that you set for the canvas only work if the Chartjs' responsive mode is false (which is true by default). Change your stats_tab.js to this and it will work.

```
    window.onload=function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        data: [1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,4]
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: false
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This will create a chart with a fixed size, with the same size on every screen, which in mho is not what you want. Better is to set the `maintainAspectRatio` to `false`, and `responsive` to `true`. This will initially try to scale your chart to match the dimensions of your canvas and if the canvas doesn't fit the screen, your chart will be re-scaled to fit on the page.

Comment: This answer should be set as approved.

Answer (score 70):

The important point is: `width` and `height` properties are not the size in px but the ratio.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

In this example, it's a 1:1 ratio. So, if your html contenair is 676 px width then your chart will be 676*675px
That can explain some common mistakes.

You can disable this feature by setting `maintainAspectRatio` to false.

Comment: you saved me bro!

Comment: That helped me a lot!

Comment: Saved my day! I did all sort of things before finding this answer

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas the 'height' is "The height of the coordinate space in CSS pixels. Defaults to 150." So, although the ratio is calculated from the width and height, they are still the size in px.

Answer (score 39):

In your options, set the `maintainAspectRatio` to `false`, and `responsive` to `true`. This will initially try to scale your chart to match the dimensions of your canvas. If the canvas doesn't fit the screen, i.e. on mobiles, your chart will be re-scaled to fit on the page.

```
window.onload=function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    data: [1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,4]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for responsive graphs.

Comment: You saved me buddy

Comment: @kurt-van-den-branden I have a bar-chart with `responsive: true,` that opens inside a bootstrap modal. If I don't use `maintainAspectRatio: false` , the graph is too tall and it goes out of the viewport (to the bottom) while if I use `maintainAspectRatio: false`  it then becomes too thin . Can you hint for a solution that will always fit some 80 of the vertical viewport lenght? Thank you

Comment: @Robert - Give your canvas or your chart container a css height of 80vh. `canvas { height: 80vh; }`

Comment: @kurt-van-den-branden thank you for the hint , I have tried to add this style to some of the bootstrap modal's DIVs but without success, can you kindly hint where this style is supposed to be added to? Thank you

Comment: Completely the correct answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

I had this exact same problem where my graph would not resize properly. To get around this issue I did two things.

1. Set the canvas tag style to a width and height of 100%. This will make sure that it always fits 100% of its containers width and height.
2. For the options value set responsive: true & maintainAspectRatio: false. This will make sure that the graph responds to updates in size while ignoring the aspect ratio.

below is the code I used:

```
    css
    #myGraph {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

    html
    <canvas id="myGraph" />
```

When you initialise the chart with the ctx set the options as below:

```
     options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false
              }
```

now when you resize your screen the graph should resize accordingly.
Note: The graph will fill the size of its container now so what ever you put your canvas into it will fill the size of that container.

Comment: It is necessary to mark the `100% !important` otherwise it is ignored (you can tell because in chrome debugger it is crossed off.

Answer (score 10):

A little late to the party, but I struggled with this problem a lot, particularly on a page with multiple charts.

This little tidbit solved it all - my charts all now fit nicely, and resize exactly with the divs they are in.

Add this to your page styles (The 8px is personal preference. Change if needed):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #canvas-holder {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 8px;
        right: 8px;
        bottom: 8px;
    }
</style>
```

For the appropriate Divs:

```
<div id="canvas-holder">
    <canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I set a height on the parent container an this works perfect. Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/7qfqgzek/) should work. Basically, just add the width and height properties to your javascript:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = 200;
ctx.canvas.height = 200;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx,.........
```

Reference: [Chart.js canvas resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847582/chart-js-canvas-resize)

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything, sadly

Comment: Hm...try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7qfqgzek/2/) -- I added some CSS and you can change the width - you'll need to play around with the values though

Comment: I figured it out, I just needed to set responsive to false.

Answer (score 4):

Below code from Chart.js documentation worked for me.
"https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html"

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.parentNode.style.width = "500px";
ctx.canvas.parentNode.style.height = "500px";
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, .....
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `<canvas>` element doesn't have a `width` & a `height` "**attribute**" (***not the css attribute***). Try setting each of them them to 1 (*Since its just a ratio*)

```
<canvas id="activeUsersPieChart" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, and I was able to keep the responsiveness of the chart!

```
  var ctxx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  ctxx.height = 80;
```

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is that the canvas will re-scale responsively to its parent.  I wanted to keep the responsiveness.  So something like this will solve the issue:

```
<div style="width:50%">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a div element and place the chart canvas inside of it, name it as canvas-holder. See below:

   ```
    <div id="canvas-holder">
       <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
   ```
2. Using CSS, specify the height and width of the canvas holder

   ```
    #canvas-holder {
       background-color: #FFFFFF;
       position: absolute;
       width: 400px;
       height: 400px;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with the chart scaling down without refresh. Per the chart.js documentation, a container with relative positioning and vh/vw assigned height was needed.

My chart was previously in a flex container and I think that was causing a lot of my scaling issues

> Detecting when the canvas size changes can not be done directly from
> the canvas element. Chart.js uses its parent container to update the
> canvas render and display sizes. However, this method requires the
> container to be relatively positioned and dedicated to the chart
> canvas only. Responsiveness can then be achieved by setting relative
> values for the container size

```
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
    <canvas id="chart" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></canvas>
</div>
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html