# Set height of chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I want to draw a horizontal bar chart with Chart.js but it keeps scaling the chart instead of using the height I assign the canvas form the script.

Is there any way to set the height of the graph from the script?

```js
var ctx = $('#myChart');

ctx.height(500);

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="graph">
  <div class="chart-legend">

  </div>
  <div class="chart">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

See code on fiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Trekels/fec0v5kj/)

Comment: You may update the ratio height vs width of your chart with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594025/chart-js-aspect-ratio-forced-height/67540672#67540672

Comment: maybe relevant: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3384  `Is it possible to make charts a fixed height? #3384
`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Seems like `var ctx = $('#myChart');` is returning a list of elements. You would need to reference the first by using `ctx[0]`.
Also height is a property, not a function.

I did it this way in my code:

```
var chartEl = document.getElementById("myChart");
chartEl.height = 500;
```

Comment: @MattSaunders It's in pixels.

Comment: please update to rename  ctx  to something like elem or same thing other than ctx as most examples use `var ctx = document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext('2d');` which is just confusing then...

Comment: for jQuery: `$("#myChart").css("height",500);`

Comment: this did not work for me.

Answer (score 609):

If you disable the maintain aspect ratio in options then it uses the available height:

```
var chart = new Chart('blabla', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeaahh! It's working fine. Thanks for this tip. Best regards man.

Comment: Whay isn't this the accepted answer? Works perfectly

Comment: Interestingly, if you `destroy()` the chart and then create it again on the same canvas second time the height of the canvas may be messed up after destroying and has to be reapplied before creation. Though, you can avoid destroying and use `update` method instead, if you don't change options.

Comment: How do I make it use available height but also set a min height?

Comment: Would make sense to explain a bit what disabling this property does (except for what is already discussed).

Comment: also disable `responsive` option if it is not disabled yet

Comment: In my case, the downside of this solution is that you have to set the responsive property to false for it to work. @bibamann solution works well with responsive being true.

Answer (score 247):

The easiest way is to create a container for the canvas and set its height:

```
<div style="height: 300px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

and set

```
options: {  
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the key here is to set `maintainAspectRatio` to `false` in the options of the graph, otherwise the `height` assigned via the `style` attribute won't actually take effect.

Comment: The suggestion of Ben is gold.

Comment: The default value for the `responsive` option is `true`.  Details: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#configuration-options

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the `height` property must be on a parent element and not on the canvas

Comment: this was the only answer that worked for me. the other answers did not work.  thanks.

Answer (score 27):

You can wrap your canvas element in a parent div, relatively positioned, then give that div the height you want, setting maintainAspectRatio: false in your options

```
//HTML
<div id="canvasWrapper" style="position: relative; height: 80vh/500px/whatever">
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
new Chart(somechart, {
options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false

/*, your other options*/

}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Based on documentation on the Chart.js website this appears to be the correct approach.

Comment: Chart container relative position is the only way to achieve responsive height apparently.
Here is the relevant doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.2/general/responsive.html#important-note

Answer (score 16):

This one worked for me:

**I set the height from HTML**

```
canvas#scoreLineToAll.ct-chart.tab-pane.active[height="200"]
canvas#scoreLineTo3Months.ct-chart.tab-pane[height="200"]
canvas#scoreLineToYear.ct-chart.tab-pane[height="200"]
```

**Then I disabled to maintaining aspect ratio**

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also set the dimensions to the canvas

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

And then set the responsive options to **false** to always maintain the chart at the size specified.

```
options: {
    responsive: false,
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I created a container and set it the desired height of the view port (depending on the number of charts or chart specific sizes):

```
.graph-container {
width: 100%;
height: 30vh;
}
```

To be dynamic to screen sizes I set the container as follows:

```
*Small media devices specific styles*/
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.graph-container {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-left:0px;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Of course very important (as have been referred to numerous times) set the following `option` properties of your chart:

```
options:{
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
}
```

Comment: maintainAspectRatio: false did the trick :)

Answer (score 7):

See, there is a mistake in the initializing statement. The **maintainAspectRatio** should come inside the **options** object as follows

```
...

options = {
   maintainAspectRatio: false,

 ...
}

...
```

Now, what you can do is set the height of the parent element of the chart, so here **div .chart** is the parent of **div #myChart**.
So, specifying the height of **div .chart** should just work fine.

Consider the following code.

```
<div class="chart" style="height: 500px;">
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Change the height according to yourself, for me **500px** just works fine ;)

Answer (score 6):

He's right. If you want to stay with jQuery you could do this

```
var ctx = $('#myChart')[0];
ctx.height = 500;
```

or

```
var ctx = $('#myChart');
ctx.attr('height',500);
```

Comment: What is that dollar sign?

Comment: $ sign is a selector and an alias of jQuery

Answer (score 5):

**You should use html height attribute for the canvas element as:**

```
<div class="chart">
    <canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though many solutions state to update the size via canvas, this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. If I use the above example and just add in your code above. My chart will not display.  This line is incorrect... --> maintainAspectRatio: false,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }

Comment: You need to edit that line so that it is -->    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
 
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }

Comment: I also have a problem changing the width? html code--> <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>

Comment: options: { maintainAspectRatio: false, responsive: true, scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero:true } }] } } Only height is changing.

Comment: This link https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/configuration/responsive.html confirms the issue mentioned earlier. Changing canvas height and width doesnt resize the graph, until we set the correct parameters within the options namespace. Note refer to links example: maintainAspectRatio is a variable within options and not outside it, hence it wasnt display.

Answer (score 3):

Set the aspectRatio property of the chart to 0 did the trick for me...

```
    var ctx = $('#myChart');

    ctx.height(500);

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
myChart.aspectRatio = 0;
```

Comment: Pretty sure `maintainAspectRatio` should be a property of `options`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the answer given by [@numediaweb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658507/6723771)

In case you're banging your head against the wall because after following the instructions to set `maintainAspectRatio=false`: I originally copied my code from an example I got on a website on using Chart.js with Angular 2+:

```
        <div style="display: block">
          <canvas baseChart
                  [datasets]="chartData"
                  [labels]="chartLabels"
                  [options]="chartOptions"
                  [legend]="chartLegend"
                  [colors]="chartColors"
                  [chartType]="chartType">
          </canvas>
        </div>
```

To make this work correctly you must remove the embedded (and unnecessary) `style="display: block"`  Instead define a class for the enclosing div, and define its height in CSS.

Once you do that, the chart should have responsive width but fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

Needed the chart to fill the parent element 100%, rather than setting height manually, and the problem was to force parent div to always fill remaining space.

After setting responsive and ratio options (check out related [chartjs doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html)), the following css did the trick:

html

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.panel {
  display: flex;

  .chart-container {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is not late but will help someone.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2.5;  
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Set the width and the height before you create the chart, adjust the height as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Size of a chartjs diagram can be simply achieved by setting the with of a surrounding container:

```
   <div style="width:400px;">
     <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
   </div>
```

But an important detail is, that you may need to `resize` your diagram after creation:

```
var ctx = $('#myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    ......
    data: {
           ........
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: true
    }
});
// now resize the new chart to fit into the canvas....
myChart.resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that maintainAspectRatio needs to be inside the options node, not at the same level as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Add one relative position element whose height is calculated from padding (works same as aspect ratio) but if you need that chart does not exceed certain maximum height then use new powerful **min** unit of css. Also add fixed fallback padding where this is not supported.

```
<div class="dashboard-charts" style="position: relative; padding-top:40%; padding-top:min(40%,530px)">
    <div style="position:absolute;width: 100%;height:100%;left: 0;top: 0">
        <canvas id="sales-dashboard-bar"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then inside options object of javascript set `maintainAspectRatio` to `false` to consider and use parent element height which in this case is absolute positioned and sized relative to the grandparent's size.

```
var mychart = new Chart(document.getElementById("sales-dashboard-bar"),{
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    }
})
```

Thus chart will scale nicely with aspect ratio of 2.5 until it hits the maximum height which is `530px` here and stops scaling afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this line in options:
**maintainAspectRatio: false**

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
  new Chart(ctx,    {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
      }]
    },
    options: {
         maintainAspectRatio: false,
         plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Location Based Alerts'
            },
             legend: {
                display: false,
                labels: {
                    color: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                }
            },
        },
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

For react, doing this works:

```
<Doughnut
  data={data}
  height="200px"
  width="200px"
  options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false }}
/>
```

Comment: This didn't work if your options is large set of values..