# How to make ng-2 chart scrollable

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I'm using ng2-chart for displaying around 500 to 1000 datas.
the problem is I need to fix the with of the chart, is there any way we can make ng-2 chart scrollable?

I tried wrapping the chart inside parent div and giving width as 100% and overflow-x: scroll to chart div, but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a ng2-charts' `<canvas baseChart>` element scrollable by *double wrapping it*.

Sample HTML :

```html
<div class="myChartWrapper">
  <div class="myChart">
    <canvas baseChart 
      [datasets]="barChartData"
      [labels]="barChartLabels"
      [options]="barChartOptions"
      [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
      [legend]="barChartLegend"
      [chartType]="barChartType">
    </canvas>
  </div>

</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```css
.myChart{
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.myChartWrapper{
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

The inner wrap `<div class="myChart">` defines the **actual** width of the chart.
The outer wrap `<div class="myChartWrapper">` defines a wrapper's width that you want to actually present to users.

[**Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-iwikrr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.
1 more thing I would like to know, it's adding a scroll, but the height of the chart is increasing as we increase the width. Is there any ways we can fix the height irrespective of the width of the chart?

Comment: Yes, just set the `maintainAspectRatio` option to false, see this answer: [set height of chart in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658507/2466342)