# how to delete empty space on chartJs canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am trying to create small horizontal bars with chartJS 2.9.4 and it happens that it has a lot of empty space on top and bottom of the bars. Is there a way to get rid of that?

I want to make the entire chart equal to the height of the bars, knowing that the height is static.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set height of chart in Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953158/set-height-of-chart-in-chart-js)

Comment: @GreenFlux sadly it doesn't, i tried all the given attributes of options that might help me here, but the image you are seeing is with the `maintainAspectRatio: false,` which is from the response of the post you mentioned.