# PrimeFaces pie chart width always 100%

Tags: primefaces, chart.js

PrimeFaces pie chart width always 100%. The style is ignored.

```html
<p:pieChart model="#{bean.pieModel}"
            style="width:200px;height:200px" >
```

Version 11.0.0

Comment: I think chart.js is to blame here. The style is rendered by the component, but it seems that chart.js changes it. You might want to wrap it in a container and and set with and height to the container.

Comment: Seems working on the showcase, so it could be some container style.

Comment: wrapping it in container works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think [chart.js](/questions/tagged/chart.js) is to blame here. The style is rendered by the component, but it seems that chart.js changes it. You might want to wrap it in a container and and set with and height to the container. So:

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px">
  <p:pieChart model="#{bean.pieModel}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be used to reduce the size of the pie chart, but if the text for the legend is too long, it is simply cut off. Height and width cannot differ.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, this fix seems to work. We already had an Extender called `customExtender` set in Java and therefore a JavaScript function `customExtender()` in the XHTML file:

```
function customExtender() {
        // old stuff
        ...
        // 1. moved legend from Java to JavaScript, because position was wrong
        this.cfg.config.options = {
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'right'
                }
            },
            // 2. DON'T make the aspect ratio 1:1
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        }

        // 3. force canvas height and width
        let canvas= document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        canvas.parentNode.style.height = '250px';
        canvas.parentNode.style.width = '615px';
    };
```

Set option `maintainAspectRatio` in the `options` to FALSE, see comment no. 2.
And force the canvas parent node to the desired `style` (width, height), see comment no. 3. I got the idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68276144/1145727.

The legend moved somehow to the top, it looked like the Java part to create and add the legend doesn't work anymore. So I moved it to JavaScript, see comment no. 1.

The legend have no wrap on to long legend texts. For me is was okay, only one of seven texts is slightly to long.